# Wrong height of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I have a strange issue with the height of the table view cells. I'm creating a custom grouped style UITableView in the storyboard. I have 4 different prototype cells for a single, top, middle and a bottom cell. Each of them has a different height. I'm already setting those heights in the storyboard, and I've also implemented the delegate method

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Just for an example: The single cell should have a height of 48. So I set the height in the storyboard to 48 and the above mentioned delegate method returns the value 48. But if I take a look at the screenshot, the single cell has actually a height of 49.

There is the same behavior for the top cell, but not for the middle and the bottom cell. That makes it even stranger.

Do you have any ideas? Where comes this extra pixel from?

Comment: Do you count the cell separator line? 48 + 1 = 49

Comment: I set the separatorStyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone, so there shouldn't be a separator. And if there was a separator, wouldn't it affect all types of cells?

Comment: Now I remember.. I used to have the same issue with grouped table view. The first cell was higher than others. I solved it with hardcode.. In heightForRowAtIndexPath {if(indexPath.row==0)return cellHeight - 1}

Comment: Thanks, I also had this idea, but I thought it's a quick-and-dirty hack. Well, it seems that I have to like it or lump it. But it's good to know that I'm not the only one who's troubling with this issue. It might be a bug in the OS.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly but it may be reason  check the height of the header and footer .